# forms not passing over the data to the SQL input

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

In this input form. The inputs dont get carried over properly to make there way into the sql database.
sqlAddUser.php = pastebin.com/W9BH0D3s
The form is:

```
<form action="sqlAddUser.php" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<label>Username:
   <input type="text" placeholder="Insert Username here!" name="user"/>
  </label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <label>Password:
    <input type="password" placeholder="Insert Password Here!" name="password" />
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <label>Email:
    <input type="text" placeholder="user@usermail.com" name="email" />
  </label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <label>First Name:
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ben" name="firstName" />
  </label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <label>Surname Name:
    <input type="text" placeholder="Brown" name="surname" />
  </label>
 </div>
 </div>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

This then when run through my INSERT INTO script justs nothing gets added to the database.

Comment: how are you getting the variables?  show your code from sqlAddUser.php

Comment: If you var_dump($_POST) on sqlAddUser.php what do you see?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/W9BH0D3s is the the code. And var_dump gives out array(0) {}

Comment: So, the problem isn't in the form code posted in the question; the problem is in the code that processes the `$_POST` array, which isn't in the question, but is available at a link provided as a comment. So, why does all this form code need to be in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `name="user"` and `$_POST['username']` change it to `$_POST['name']`
or change `name="user"` to `name="username"` - they need to match.

---

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert Username here!" name="user"/>
                                                             ^^^^

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
                                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

as per your pastebin file http://pastebin.com/W9BH0D3s from [`your commment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776102/forms-not-passing-over-the-data-to-the-sql-input/25776277?noredirect=1#comment40312159_25776102)

```
<?php 

                // Create connection
        $con=mysqli_connect("*****", "******", "*****", "*****");

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstName']);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['surname']);

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, firstName, surname)
    VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$firstName', '$surname')");    
?>
```

---

**Edit:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $con=mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

if(isset($_POST['username'])){ $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']); }
if(isset($_POST['password'])){ $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']); }
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']); }
if(isset($_POST['firstName'])){ $firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstName']); }
if(isset($_POST['surname'])){ $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['surname']); }

$sql="INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, firstName, surname) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$firstName', '$surname')"; 
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error:' . mysqli_error($con));
}
var_dump($_POST);
echo "1 record added";
}
```